# MeteorJS: One login user for unlimited devices

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth, patreon

I'm working on a Meteor Web App that uses the Patreon API to check if they are Patrons of the site or not.  If they are then the Web App should log them in and then display the extra buttons with extra functionalities that only Patrons can use.

Currently, what I'm thinking is having a login button that calls the oauth link of Patreon.  Then after the user logs in and allows the Web App access to their Patreon profile to check if they are supportors of the site or not, then the Meteor logs them in.

In order to simplify the logging in process, I am thinking of logging all of the different Patrons using the same single login name and password (e.g. username: 'user1', password: 'password1').

That means if there are a thousand Patrons using a thousand different devices to login, I am thinking of all logging all of them in using a single username and password in Meteor to simplify things since this will only happen after they have authenticated themselves through the Patreon oauth API.

Does this sound like it will work? and is a acceptable way of doing things?

Comment: Logging in from many multiple device with same user basically works. Problematic is updating data that affects the user (repsective all users). A good way would be to have a second user (with higher roles / permissions) that is capable of updating data, while the mass-user account is read only.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will likely require *more* work because you would have to work around Meteor's accounts system instead of working with it.

I would stick with Meteor accounts with an OAuth flow instead of passwords for each user